# Setting Global Variable from ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Very new to C# so the global Variables are still a mystery and issue for me.

I'm trying to create a dynamic Variable using a Combobox but it doesn't like anything I'm trying to throw at it.

I'm hoping Someone and see my mistake and show me what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried placing the if statements in various locations like on the button click and SelectedIndexChanged but still not working correctly.

when I click on my button to run the script it says it could not find the file and the ScriptName Variable is saying it is not used anywhere.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;



namespace ServerStatusChecks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        public string ScriptName { get; set; }
        static string RunScriptResult;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }


        private string LoadScript(string filename)
        {

            try
            {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from our file.
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                {


                    // use a string builder to get all our lines from the file
                    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();

                    // string to hold the current line
                    string curLine;

                    // loop through our file and read each line into our
                    // stringbuilder as we go along
                    while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // read each line and MAKE SURE YOU ADD BACK THE
                        // LINEFEED THAT IT THE ReadLine() METHOD STRIPS OFF
                        fileContents.Append(curLine + "\n");
                    }

                    // call RunScript and pass in our file contents
                    // converted to a string
                    return fileContents.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Let the user know what went wrong.
                string errorText = "The file could not be read:";
                errorText += e.Message + "\n";
                return errorText;

            }
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            // run our script and put the result into our textbox
            // NOTE: make sure to change the path to the correct location of your script

        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RunScriptResult = RunScript(LoadScript(ScriptName));
        }

        // Takes script text as input and runs it, then converts
        // the results to a string to return to the user
        private string RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
            get {
                return ScriptName;
            }
            set {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    string ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script1.ps1";
                }
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    string ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script2.ps1";
                }
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    string ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script3.ps1";
                }
            }
            // create Powershell runspace
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

            // open it
            runspace.Open();

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
            // remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script
            // "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            // execute the script
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            // close the runspace
            pipeline.Dispose();
            runspace.Close();

            // convert the script result into a single string
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());

            }

            // return the results of the script that has
            // now been converted to text
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        // helper method that takes your script path, loads up the script
        // into a variable, and passes the variable to the RunScript method
        // that will then execute the contents
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\utils");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.ps1");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = RunScriptResult;
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Working Script

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;



namespace ServerStatusChecks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        public string ScriptName { get; set; }
        static string RunScriptResult;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }


        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            // run our script and put the result into our textbox
            // NOTE: make sure to change the path to the correct location of your script

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script1.ps1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script2.ps1";
                    break;
                default:
                    ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script3.ps1";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loadScript = LoadScript(ScriptName);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loadScript)) return;

            RunScriptResult = RunScript(loadScript);
        }

        private static string LoadScript(string filename)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filename)) return "";

            var fileContents = new StringBuilder();

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                fileContents.Append(line + "\n");
            }

            return fileContents.ToString();
        }

        private static string RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
            //should start from this line
            // create Powershell runspace
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
            // remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script
            // "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.
            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            // execute the script
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            // close the runspace
            pipeline.Dispose();
            runspace.Close();


            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());

            }

            // return the results of the script that has
            // now been converted to text
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        // helper method that takes your script path, loads up the script
        // into a variable, and passes the variable to the RunScript method
        // that will then execute the contents
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\utils");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.ps1");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = RunScriptResult;
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

1. This property:
   `private string RunScript(string scriptText)` should not be a property. It should be a method. Remove the `get` and the `set` from it. And, probably you'll need to make it `static`. Also, I would not use the same name for the method as the property on the top.
2. Add this logic:

   ```
   if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
       ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script1.ps1";
   }
   if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
       ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script2.ps1";
   }
   if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
   {
       ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script3.ps1";
   }
   ```

   to `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. Notice that I deleted the multiple variable declarations. You should be able to access the one that is on top.
3. Change the `StreamReader` for a simple `File.ReadAllLines(ScriptName);` This will return an array of every line in the file. If you really need to loop through every line and append `\n` you can do it as well. It keeps the code simpler.

So, my version would be like this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
   {
       case 1:
           ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script2.ps1";
           break;
       case 2:
           ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script3.ps1";
           break;
       default:
           ScriptName = @"c:\utils\Script1.ps1";
           break;
    }
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var loadScript = LoadScript(ScriptName);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loadScript)) return;

    RunScriptResult = RunScript(loadScript);
}

private static string LoadScript(string filename)
{       
    if (!File.Exists(filename)) return "";

    var fileContents = new StringBuilder();

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
       fileContents.Append(line + "\n");
    }

    return fileContents.ToString();
}

private static string RunScript(string scriptText)
{         
    //should start from this line
    // create Powershell runspace
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    //bla bla bla bla
    return "something";
}
```

Everything else, should be the same

Comment: I've set the logic to the SelectedIndexChanged however Removing the property like suggested would also stop the background worker also would it not? specifically RunScriptResult = RunScript(LoadScript(ScriptName));

Comment: Yes, but that logic should not be inside the property. The background worker and its related logic should only run once the button is clicked

Comment: If you want to use that property as a method remove the `get` and the `set`. You will probably need to make it `static` as well

Comment: ok a lot to change, I've done 1 2 . I'll have to also edit the pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText); as well and it may cause a casade of changes as well. currently trying to work on 3 and 4 but I'm still a novice so it may take me a bit. EDIT: Noticed your edit. will try now

Comment: Thanks @luis-lavieri! I've added the code that worked for me. I did have to change what was Script1 vs script3 as the array builds it in alphabetical order so changing it caused to not run the right scripts at first.